# Finding first vowel of a word in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am having trouble finding the index of the first vowel of a inputted string. When putting in the string "elephant" , "hello" , "spa" they work properly, however when I input "spam" it does not work, it returned the number 3 instead of 2. I am having trouble finding why it satisfies the else statement but not the initial if condition. I am also trying to put a condition that if there are no vowels in the string, then it should print out the index of the last character in the string. Below is my code:

```
def find_first_vowel(word):
    i = 0   
    while i < len(word):
        i+= 1
        if word[i] in vowels:
            return i
        else:
            return len(word)-1
    return i

print(find_first_vowel("spam"))
```

Comment: What happens if the vowel is the first letter, wouldn't you always get back 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code always return `len(word)-1` if the character in position `1` is not a vowel. Also `elephant` didn't work and `spa` works only because of the bug I mentioned, it returns `2` which is `len(word)-1` and not the index of the vowel found. Try debug your code line by line and you'll figure it out very quickly.

This could be a working code that return `-1` if there's no vowel, else return the index of the first vowel found.

```
def find_first_vowel(word):
    i = 0   
    while i < len(word):
        if word[i] in vowels:
            return i
        i += 1
    return -1
```

**EDIT**

If you want to return the last character if there's no vowels just change `return -1` with `return len(word) - 1`. Here:

```
def find_first_vowel(word):
    i = 0   
    while i < len(word):
        if word[i] in vowels:
            return i
        i += 1
    return len(word) - 1
```

Comment: This works however I am trying to put the condition that if the inputted word has no vowels, then it should just print the index of the last character

Comment: Just edit `return -1` with `return len(word)-1` in my code, but please notice that you would have the same result as if there was a vowel in the last character.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to handle tracking the index for you

```
vowels = set('aeiou')

def find_first_vowel(word):
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter in vowels:
            return index
    return index  # Returns last index if no vowels.  You could also return None, or raise an error
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `return` statement jumps out of your `while` loop immediately, without looking at the rest of the word. Additional problem: since you start with `i += 1`, the function never even looks at the first character, which would be `word[0]`.

I think your main issue is that you meant for your `else` statement to be executed if the `while` loop completed and exited without finding a vowel. As indented, though, it's part of the `if` statement in the `while` loop, and executes whenever the second character isn't a vowel. You want something more like this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(word):
    if word[i] in vowels:
        return i
    i += 1
```

And then whatever you want the function to return if the word has no vowels.